# which php use Psysh

Tags: php, ms-access, read-eval-print-loop

I installed Psysh (from http://psysh.org) with Cygwin and get it running. I tried to use php write/read microsoft access database. But it does not work so far. I have two php installed. First one installed by web platform installer and second one installed by xampp. How can I know which php installation psych use so I can work on. Thank you.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.access

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answer my own question. psysh use the php installion showed on path variable.